# two physicians I ran them by

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The hospital’s $185,037.45 bill includes $13,500 for an MRI of my elbow, $9,500 for a CAT scan and $17,797.12 for two x-rays. “Laboratory” expenses—primarily related, I’m guessing, to blood tests carried out throughout my stay—total $44,787.96. The bill for my semi-private hospital room is $54,000, or $18,000 per night. The hospital’s charges strike me—and **two physicians I ran them by**—as high.

> Source: [Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/an-elbow-injury-exposes-the-exorbitant-costs-of-health-care/)

Does "ran them by" mean "consulted the physicians about the costs"?
Collins Dictionary has this - "If you run something by someone, you tell them about it or mention it, to see if they think it is a good idea, or can understand it." So I guess the "them" in the "ran them by" refers to the costs. Not sure whether I am on the right track.

Comment: Yes. The phrase is often used in the context of costs.

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Compare *If you want to make an offer on a new house, [run it by me first](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22run+it+by+me+first%22) and I'll tell you if the price is reasonable.* But the idiom can be used to ask for / describe initial sight / approval / assessment of ***any*** planned future action, not just things involving "costs".